# Is there a restriction to cursor sizes in VB.net

Tags: wpf, windows, vb.net, cursor

My application makes use of a custom cursor loaded from a predefined file (.cur) during runtime.  I know windows uses a standard 32x32 pixels cursor or a 48x48 pixel cursor for high DPI devices.

The cursor I want to use in my application however is much larger.  A small cursor is displayed correctly when I use `Mouse.SetCursor(_CustomCursor)`.  When a larger cursor is chosen, I don't see any cursor.  It would seem that the cursor loads correctly but cannot be displayed.

Note: Currently a static .cur cursor is acceptable.

Is there a way to display larger cursors in my application and if there is a limit on the size, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a restriction to cursor sizes?

Yes, it's a system restriction. Not just for VB.NET...

To get the max size of the Cursor you can use, you should query the [SystemParameters.CursorHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.cursorheight%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [SystemParameters.CursorWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.cursorwidth%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) properties.

As stated by MSDN these properties are mapped to the `SM_CYCURSOR` and`SM_CXCURSOR` properties respectivly.
As you can read in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> SM_CXCURSOR
>   13
>   The width of a cursor, in pixels. ***The system cannot create cursors of other sizes.***

and

> SM_CYCURSOR
>   14
>   The height of a cursor, in pixels. ***The system cannot create cursors of other sizes.***

Comment: How do games etc. create their own custom cursor?

Comment: They dont use vb, for starters

Comment: @ChristianSauer The method in my new answer might remove some of the size restrictions on cursors and allows for any custom cursor to be displayed, perhaps game developers follow a similar approach.

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to find a work around to the problem on the size restriction.

As mentioned on [Cursor from BitMap](http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/375571-cursor-bitmap) one can create a cursor of arbitrary size from a bitmap.

The code to achieve this is as follows:

```
Dim bm As New Bitmap(60, 60)                 'Or from a bitmap file
Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bm)   
g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, 0, 0, 60, 60)  'For a simple blue rectangle cursor
Dim ptrCur As IntPtr = bm.GetHicon
Dim CustomCursor As Cursor
CustomCursor = New Cursor(ptrCur)
Me.Cursor = CustomCursor                     'Set the application cursor to be custom
```

The hotspot is automatically set to the centre of the bitmap. Here is a preview of the results:

[image: Large Blue Cursor]

This code works well on a Windows forms application. With a WPF application an 'invalid extension for cursor' exception is thrown.  Will be looking into resolving it (any suggestions welcome).

**EDIT:** In WPF a restriction of 96 pixels is applied to any dimension of the cursor, anything bigger will not display.

Comment: As you mentioned, this will work only for a winforms implementation, not WPF... Also the main problem with this solution is not being able to choose where the hotspot is located...